# TypeScript way to do multiple imports at once?

Tags: typescript

Since inbuilt modules in TypeScript will be strictly typed if `import` is used, is there a way to do the equivalent of the node/CommonJS 'single require'?

Eg, rather than:

```
const x = require("x"),
    y = require("y")
```

Do something like:

```
import x = require("x"),
    y = require("y")
```

The above is an error using ES2017 target for TSC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

There is no syntax to support this.

`import x = require('x'), y = require('y')` suggests `import` is somethin like `var`, `let` or `const`, but it is not. It carries special meaning in the language.

I think that's why they make the choice of not including it into the language.

IMO, it is cleaner and easier to maintain when they are separated into separate lines.

It's the same arguments of `var x = 1, y = 2;` vs `var x = 1;\n var y = 2;`

By the way, starting from ES2015, you will use the `import ... from ...` syntax instead. Unless you are importing commonJS library.

In ES2015, there is also no syntax of importing multiple modules "at once" either.

And targeting ES2017 would not work with `import x = require('x')` syntax.

You have to do `import * as x from 'x'` which gets into interop and it has other problems.

You can learn more from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16093

UPDATE: with TypeScript@2.7 released, you can now do `import EditableElement from 'Transformer'` directly.

Turn on `esModuleInterop` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Yeah I'm importing a commonJS library (ie, 99% of the million modules on npm!)